# Count numbers that don't match between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My original query is to count by month how many items have never been ordered.

I have created a sql fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e89a7/2

And put together the query below

```
SELECT COUNT(ItemNo)
FROM Item
WHERE ItemNo NOT IN 
(SELECT ItemNo
FROM Order1)
```

However this doesn't do what I want and I wonder if I'm going about it the wrong way. I need this to be grouped by ordered month and year but the NOT IN clause doesn't allow me to do this.

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE Item (
    ItemNo varchar(10),
    MonthStocked varchar(10),
    YearStocked varchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE Order1 (
    OrderNo int,
    ItemNo varchar(10),
    MonthOrdered varchar(10),
    YearOrdered varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO Item (ItemNo, MonthStocked,YearStocked)
VALUES ('111','Feb', 2017),
('222','Jan',  2018),
('333','Feb', 2017),
('444','Feb', 2017),
('555','Jan', 2017),
('666','Jan', 2017);

INSERT INTO Order1 (OrderNo, ItemNo,MonthOrdered,YearOrdered)
VALUES ('897', '111', 'Dec', '2017'),
('657', '222', 'Nov', '2017'),
('896', '333', 'Nov' , '2017'),
('867', '333', 'Dec' , '2017'),
('234', '444', 'Nov' , '2017');
```

**desired output:**

```
| ItemsNotOrdered  |     Month    |     Year    |
|------------------|--------------|-------------|
|                3 |          Nov |        2017 |
|                4 |          Dec |        2017 |
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and its expected result. And the query attempt for all 3 columns.

Comment: I've edited you question to add the sample data from your sqlfiddle link. SqlFiddle is great, but sample data should be in the question's body.

Comment: For this kind of thing you have to start with a table that has the months you want to report on. Then you can use a left join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the cartesian product using `CROSS JOIN` between all unique `ItemNo` to all unique ordered months and years. The resulting product will then be outer join to table `Items` on three conditions. The inexisting `ItemNo` are simply the one you are looking for.

```
SELECT  b.MonthOrdered, b.YearOrdered,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN c.ItemNo IS NULL THEN 1 END)
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT ItemNo FROM Item) a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT  DISTINCT MonthOrdered, YearOrdered FROM Order1) b
        LEFT JOIN Order1 c
            ON a.ItemNo = c.ItemNo
                AND b.MonthOrdered = c.MonthOrdered 
                AND b.YearOrdered = c.YearOrdered 
 GROUP BY b.MonthOrdered, b.YearOrdered
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/39466/1).

If `ItemNo` is unique, eliminate the subquery and use the table directly.

```
SELECT  b.MonthOrdered, b.YearOrdered,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN c.ItemNo IS NULL THEN 1 END)
FROM    Item a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT  DISTINCT MonthOrdered, YearOrdered FROM Order1) b
        LEFT JOIN Order1 c
            ON a.ItemNo = c.ItemNo
                AND b.MonthOrdered = c.MonthOrdered 
                AND b.YearOrdered = c.YearOrdered 
 GROUP BY b.MonthOrdered, b.YearOrdered
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/39466/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross join` to generate all the item/year/month combinations.  Then `left join` and `group by` to get the results you want:

```
select ym.mon, ym.mon, count(*)
from item i cross join
     (select distinct MonthOrdered as mon, YearOrdered as yr from order1
     ) ym left join
     order1 o
     on i.itemno = o.itemno and ym.mon = o.MonthOrdered and ym.yr = o.YearOrdered 
where o.itemno is null
group by ym.yr, ym.mon;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e89a7/75) is the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using OUTER APPLY

```
SELECT   DISTINCT 
         MonthOrdered,
         YearOrdered,
         ItemsNotOrdered
FROM     Order1 o
OUTER APPLY (
         SELECT COUNT(ItemNo) ItemsNotOrdered
         FROM   Item i
         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT  ItemNo 
            FROM    Order1 o2
            WHERE   i.ItemNo = o2.ItemNo
            AND     o2.MonthOrdered = o.MonthOrdered
            AND     o2.YearOrdered = o.YearOrdered
         ) 
) ino
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like your desired output as it misses months where nothing is sold.  I also don't like that months don't sort.

```
declare @item table (ItemNo varchar(10), MonthStocked varchar(10), YearStocked varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @Item (ItemNo, MonthStocked,YearStocked)
VALUES ('111','Feb', 2017),
       ('222','Jan', 2018),
       ('333','Feb', 2017),
       ('444','Feb', 2017),
       ('555','Jan', 2017),
       ('666','Jan', 2017);

declare @Order1 table (OrderNo int, ItemNo varchar(10), MonthOrdered varchar(10), YearOrdered varchar(10)) 
INSERT INTO @Order1 (OrderNo, ItemNo,MonthOrdered,YearOrdered)
VALUES ('897', '111', 'Dec', '2017'),
       ('657', '222', 'Nov', '2017'),
       ('896', '333', 'Nov', '2017'),
       ('867', '333', 'Dec', '2017'),
       ('234', '444', 'Nov', '2017');

declare @itemCount int = (select count(distinct ItemNo) from @item);

with CTEyymm as 
( select MonthStocked as mm, YearStocked as yy
    from @item 
  union
  select MonthOrdered, YearOrdered
    from @Order1
)

select yymm.yy, yymm.mm
     , (@itemCount - count(distinct(o.ItemNo))) as cnt  
  from CTEyymm yymm 
  left join @order1 o 
    on o.YearOrdered  = yymm.yy 
   and o.MonthOrdered = yymm.mm 
 group by yymm.yy, yymm.mm
 order by yymm.yy, yymm.mm;
```

If you don't care about blank months then just:

```
select o.YearOrdered, o.MonthOrdered
     , (@itemCount - count(distinct(o.ItemNo))) as cnt  
  from @order1 o 
 group by o.YearOrdered, o.MonthOrdered
 order by o.YearOrdered, o.MonthOrdered
```